# 1-Byte response issue in transceive function in Broadcom NFC Android stack

Tags: android, nfc, broadcom

I am using an NFC Tag Type 2. I am having a problem with 1-Byte ACK/NACK responses when calling a transceive() function running the Broadcom NFC Android stack. This problem doesn't happen with the NXP NFC Android stack. For example, the ACK response of a Write command is defined as 0xAh (according to the NFC Forum Tag Type 2 protocol). If the NFC tag replies something else rather than 0xAh, the Broadcom NFC stack will consider this as NACK. This issue doesn't occur in the NXP NFC stack.

**Broadcom NFC stack**

**In /platform/packages/apps/Nfc/nci/jni/NativeNfcTag.cpp

In function “nativeNfcTag_doTransceive()” line 890**

```
static jbyteArray nativeNfcTag_doTransceive (JNIEnv* e, jobject, jbyteArray data, jboolean raw, jintArray statusTargetLost)
    {
    ..
    ..
    if ((natTag.getProtocol () == NFA_PROTOCOL_T2T) &&
                natTag.isT2tNackResponse (sTransceiveData, sTransceiveDataLen))
            {
                isNack = true;
            }

            if (sTransceiveDataLen)
            {
                if (!isNack) {
                    // marshall data to java for return
                    result.reset(e->NewByteArray(sTransceiveDataLen));
                    if (result.get() != NULL) {
                        e->SetByteArrayRegion(result.get(), 0, sTransceiveDataLen, (jbyte *) sTransceiveData);
                    }
                    else
                        ALOGE ("%s: Failed to allocate java byte array", __FUNCTION__);
                } // else a nack is treated as a transceive failure to the upper layers

                free (sTransceiveData);
                sTransceiveData = NULL;
                sTransceiveDataLen = 0;
            }
       ..
       ..
}
```

When we look at function isT2tNackResponse() in /platform/packages/apps/Nfc/nci/jni/NfcTag.cpp  line 1212

```
    bool NfcTag::isT2tNackResponse (const UINT8* response, UINT32 responseLen)
    {
        static const char fn [] = "NfcTag::isT2tNackResponse";
        bool isNack = false;

        if (responseLen == 1)
        {
            if (response[0] == 0xA) // line 1212: T2tNackResponse always returns NACK if the first byte is NOT 0xA 
                isNack = false; //an ACK response, so definitely not a NACK
            else
                isNack = true; //assume every value is a NACK
        }
        ALOGD ("%s: return %u", fn, isNack);
        return isNack;
}
```

**NXP NFC stack**

**The same function in the NXP NFC stack
In /platform/packages/apps/Nfc/nxp/jni/com_android_nfc_NativeNfcTag.cpp

In function “com_android_nfc_NativeNfcTag_doTransceive()” line 853**

```
static jbyteArray com_android_nfc_NativeNfcTag_doTransceive(JNIEnv *e,
   jobject o, jbyteArray data, jboolean raw, jintArray statusTargetLost)
{

..
..
/* Copy results back to Java *
     * In case of NfcA and raw, also check the CRC in the response
     * and cut it off in the returned data.
     */
    if ((nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->length > 2) && checkResponseCrc) { // line 853
        if (crc_valid(nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->buffer, nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->length)) {
            result = e->NewByteArray(nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->length - 2);
            if (result != NULL) {
                e->SetByteArrayRegion(result, 0,
                 nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->length - 2,
                 (jbyte *)nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->buffer);
            }
        }
    } else {
        result = e->NewByteArray(nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->length);
        if (result != NULL) {
            e->SetByteArrayRegion(result, 0,
             nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->length,
             (jbyte *)nfc_jni_transceive_buffer->buffer);
        }
    }
..
..
}
```

In the NXP NFC stack, everything is forwarded to Java and returned to the transceive() function.

Any help/comment would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. The problem is actually with the NFC Forum NCI standard, on which the Broadcom stack is based. The protocol messages in the NCI standard do not distinguish between 4-bit ACK/NAK responses and normal responses of 1 byte (+ CRC, which is stripped). Both are represented by a single byte. The Broadcom stack (has to) interpret them as ACK/NAK. Hopefully, this will soon be fixed in an update to the standard and the software stack.

Comment: Thank you, NFC guy. I wish this will happen very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an issue only for NFC Forum Tag Type 2? In the code, it seems that the other tag types aren't effected by this. Tag Type 3,4 and NfcV's 1-Byte raw data won't be filtered. I didn't follow the discussion in the NFC Forum. What's the main reason we need to distinguish between 4-bit responses and 1-byte data?